# Sequence of $p$ and $d$ that satisfy $d=q+r$

Tags: number-theory

I was doing a number theory-related problem when I came upon these two numbers: $2017$ and $64$. If you do a simple division you'll find $2017=64\times31+33$. Here, interestingly, $64=31+33$, which means the divisor is the sum of the quotient and the remainder.

So I was wondering if there's any special sequence that includes pairs of dividend and divisors such that the divisor is the sum of the quotient and the remainder? (basically, are there any patterns?)

(There are obviously other numbers, such as $15$ and $8$. $15=8\times1+7$.

The question is better formulated below:

Suppose a positive integer $p$. We know $p$ can be expressed as $dq + r$, such that $d$, $q$, and $r$ are all positive integers.
Let $p$ observe a special property such that $d = q + r$ hence $p = dq + r = (q + r)q + r = q^2 + qr + r$. Find a sequence of $p$s and $d$s, such that $p$ can be expressed as $q^2 + qr + r$.

Comment: consider the set of all pairs $(p,d)$ such that $d-1$ divides $p-1$ and $\sqrt{p}\leq  d<p$

Comment: all odd numbers satisfy your condition , for $p=2 k+1$ take $d=k+1$ and $q=1$ and $r=k$.

Comment: that's right. for example $(43,22)$ take $k=21$. But there are other solutions for $p=43$: $(43,7)$, $(43,8)$, and $(43,15)$

Comment: @Lozenges Thanks! By a brief look your answer seems to make sense.

Comment: By the way , @Ahmad I think there are also even numbers that satisfy that (or numbers beyond your category).